# MATLAB - callback excecution of edit box

Tags: matlab, user-interface, focus

As it is referenced in MATLAB documentation for edit box uicontrol or stated in this
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830207/how-do-i-detect-focus-loss-from-a-text-edit-object), when another component or menu bar or background GUI is clicked, the edit box callback gets executed. But in my attempts to use this functionality, I haven't been able so far to see the callback execution unless there is a change of edit box text or Enter key is pressed. What I'm trying to achieve is to execute edit box callback whenever there is focus loss from edit box even when nothing has been entered. Please enlighten me about what I'm missing here and how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that the callback gets executed when the edit text loses focus _only if its contents have been edited_. At least that's what I'm getting here

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case but what about the documentation?

Comment: This seems to support our observations: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html#f10-1001464

Comment: OK. that's for R2014a version but in my 2009 offline documentation, it says as I have previously stated.

Comment: I'm testing both in 2010b and 2008a, and the callback is not executed unless text has been changed

Comment: Info for edit box in _Specifying the Uicontrol Style_ section of this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html seems to accompany my claims

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying Java object has a callback called `FocusLostCallback` that'll do what you want - execute when the object's focus is lost, even if you changed nothing.

You'll need [`findjobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects) from the MATLAB File Exchange. Then, get the Java handle and set the callback as usual (make sure the `uicontrol` is visible when you try to get the Java handle):

```
jh = findjobj(myEditBox); % myEditBox is a uicontrol handle
set(jh, 'FocusLostCallback', @myCallback);
```

A more complete list of the undocumented `uicontrol` callbacks can be found at [Yair Altman's Undocumented MATLAB blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uicontrol-callbacks).

Comment: So the Info in http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html for edit box is not explicitly true

Comment: Based on the statement: "To execute the callback routine for an edit text control, type in the desired text and then do one of the following:

    (a) Click another component, the menu bar, or the background of the GUI;

    (b) For a single line editable text box, press Enter.

    (c)For a multiline editable text box, press Ctl+Enter.", it looks like it's not true when nothing has changed in the editbox. Note that it does still execute the callback when you do hit Enter. This may be something to alert The MathWorks about.

Answer (score 1):

This method work perfectly with single-line textbox, but it has any effect with multi-line textbox (uicontrol, style edit, max = 2)